# Spring Security 401(Unauthorized) using UserDetailsService, jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security

I have an embedded h2-databse where I store the user details and trying to authorize the request using data from these stored users but onlu permitAll() requests are working.

Security Configuration Class : The error most likely is coming from Autorization Configuration.

```
package engine;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"engine"})
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private final APIUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(APIUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
         http.csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/quizzes/**", "/api/quizzes").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/", "/actuator/shutdown","/h2-console/**", "/api/register").permitAll()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Class implementing UserDetails I have hard-coded a few things, not required in db. I have also attached the User class below.

```
package engine;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class APIUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public APIUserDetails(User user) {
        this.userName = user.getEmail();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
    }

    public APIUserDetails() {
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

User Details Service

```
package engine;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class APIUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public APIUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(userName);
        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not Found: " + userName));
        return user.map(APIUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

User

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Email(regexp = ".+@.+\\..+")
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 5)
    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String role;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Quiz> quizzes;

    public User() {
        this.quizzes = new ArrayList<>();
        this.role = "ROLE_USER";
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public List<Quiz> getQuizzes() {
        return quizzes;
    }

    public void setQuizzes(List<Quiz> quizzes) {
        this.quizzes = quizzes;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

User Repository

```
package engine;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

On using GET /api/quizzes

```
Request received for GET '/api/quizzes':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@309aa9c2

servletPath:/api/quizzes
pathInfo:null
headers: 
authorization: Basic dGVzdEBnb29nbGUuY29tOnF3ZXJ0eQ==
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
accept: */*
postman-token: 06cb7b25-176d-411c-9e8d-47b40e5a7820
host: localhost:8889
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2020-11-14 01:58:42.790  WARN 6630 --- [nio-8889-exec-2] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2020-11-14 01:58:42.795  INFO 6630 --- [nio-8889-exec-2] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************



Request received for GET '/error':

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@54bf9f9a

servletPath:/error
pathInfo:null
headers: 
authorization: Basic dGVzdEBnb29nbGUuY29tOnF3ZXJ0eQ==
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
accept: */*
postman-token: 06cb7b25-176d-411c-9e8d-47b40e5a7820
host: localhost:8889
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

Comment: do you have a log or what does `loadUserByUsername` return?

Comment: **UserDetailsService** interface rquires `loadByUsername()` method which returns a class implementing UserDetails.. UserRepository gets user details using `findByEmail()` then maps to userDetails class.

Comment: I see that you have ROLE_USER in User, but Spring Security will determine authorization using the UserDetails from user.map(APIUserDetails::new).get(); Can you post that logic? Did you ensure that the UserDetails has a GrantedAuthority with ROLE_USER?

Comment: @RobWinch In `APIUserDetails` class I specify granted authorities using the override function `getAuthorities()` where I convert String USER_ROLE to a list of `SimpleGrantedAuthority`

Comment: What HTTP method / URL are you requesting that fails? Can you post your logs when you make that request?

Comment: @RobWinch I made a few changes and now its showing Unauthorized 401..Anyhow I am trying to GET /api/quizzes.. the reponse rn `{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-13T19:58:55.534+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/api/quizzes"
}`

Comment: I ran the debugger and the UserDetails is not getting authenticated..And this is the place where it goes wrong i guess `   additionalAuthenticationChecks(user,
     (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);`   `org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@9572dcd9: Principal: test@google.com; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Not granted any authorities`

Comment: How are you authenticating? I'd expect you would have something like http.httpBasic() so that there is  something reading in the username/password and trying to validate it.

Comment: @RobWinch I just edited with changed authorization configuration in SecurityConfig class.

Comment: Are the passwords in your database hashed using BCrypt? They should start with `$2a` if they are. Something to try is to change APIUserDetails.getPassword to always return `$2a$10$qagfv2rU1PX6TLyHuGFFMulsBdo0HJ8Q3n1.eKcLISjuioFWjgaUO` Then try using a password of `password` to log in.

Comment: Ok, ooooo yes,yes,yes.. That seems to be the case.. sorry dumb mistake.. I will change the `User.setPassword()` and it should work .. Thank you..

Comment: No worries. Just make sure that your password in the database is hashed.I think changing the setter may make it double hashed because when it is read in from the database your ORM will invoke the setter with the already hashed value.

Comment: @RobWinch It worked I only used it on `setPassword()` not on `getPassword()` so I dont think its getting double hashed.. Also how do i close this.. U can post ur comment as answer and then?

Comment: Glad you got it working. I posted an answer that you can accept as right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` ensure that the passwords in the database are hashed properly. To check you should ensure that the password starts with `$2a`.

**Note** that is safe to remove the following code because Spring Security automatically uses the `UserDetails` and `PasswordEncoder` exposed as a Bean:

```
private final APIUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(APIUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```